# georeferenced points in python, if we know relative coordinates

Tags: coordinates

I have a square with relative coordinates (that are known)

```
(x1,y2)--------(x2,y2)
   |              |
   |              |
(x1,y1)--------(x1,y2)
```

Those points have known GPS coordinates (in projected system).
What kind of transformation do I need to apple to x1,y1,x2,y2, so I can bring the relative coordinates to absolute?

In other words, if x1=0, y1=0, x2=20,y=20 and I know that (x1,y1)-->(utm_x,utm_y)

P.S.
Apparently, I do not care about the corners, But in my square grid, there are 100s of xy pairs, that need to be rotated.

[image]

EDIT:

I think I figure it out
I calculate the arctan between the two points

```
l1=np.abs(x[4]-x[1])
l2=np.abs(y[4]-y[1])
alpha=np.arctan2(l2,l1)
```

Every point(p1,p2) along the grid

```
    new_x=p1*np.cos(-alpha) - (p2)*np.sin(-alpha) + x[4]
    new_y=p1*np.sin(-alpha) + p2*np.cos(-alpha) + y[4]
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your "relative" and "absolute". GPS are "absolute". A point has one and only one coordinate. Relative is usually when you do not know the absolute coordinate of every point, but the relative differences. UTM may not be unique. A battle field could have different coordinates, depending on reference sector (and it is the usefulness of UTM). Maybe if you have a real example, we may understand better.

Comment: x1,y1,x2,y2 are measured with a measuring tape, deployed on earth (relative distance from a house for instance). But (x1,y1) has utm coordinate (100000,20000) and and (x2,y2) has (10018,200019), absolute coordiantes(...about). So if that was arcgis, you can corelate the x1,y1--> (10000,20000) and x2,y2--->(10018,20001) and everything rotates.

Comment: With UTM, you just sum meters with the coordinates. Within a zone (and also partly on the nearby zones) you can assume UTM are Cartesian coordinates in a metric system (so flat surface). This is the reason of UTM: simple additions (within a battle field region, which it is enough for many purposes). In Arcgis you should tell the region of UTM, and remember that x,y and lat,long have inverted axis. Note: UTM comes in two version, the old one and the new one compatible with WGS-84 (and so with GPS)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I think this https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/272338/plotting-points-using-x-y-coordinates-from-point-on-map-in-qgis explains a bit better what I want to do. Does this helps?

Comment: UTM is already one of the x,y. Now you need to find the right EPGS for your UTM zone. E.g. https://epsg.io/32632  (just google for `UTM` and your zone

Comment: I don't think I explain correctly. Assume you go out of your house and lay a measuring tape 50m. The first point in the tape (0m) has a lat1,lon2. The last point of the tape (50m) has lat2,lon2. How can I convert the measurements from the tape, every 1m, to lat,lon.

Comment: You have a UTM coordinate. then it is just a Cartesian plane (as I wrote). Just do the normal geometric calculation you learn at school. Note: you DO NO MEASURE 0m. You measure distances. use x1, y1 as UTM, and then the distance (your relative coordinates). It is just cartesian (inside UTM). Then when you have a point you want to get lat, long, just convert it (e.g. to WGS-84). Draws it in a paper. You are mixing up things, and so it seems more complex. It is easy (but do a sketch please, so you will see it).

Comment: I edited the first post. Rephrasing, I know the UTM (projected) system coordinate from GPS in the two corners. Let's forget about lat,lon, not relevant. I want to know for each points in my regular grid, the coordinates in utm.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, see the solution in the edited post.

I calculate the arctan between the two points (x4,y4) (x1,y1) from GPS coordinates

```
l1=np.abs(x[4]-x[1])
l2=np.abs(y[4]-y[1])
alpha=np.arctan2(l2,l1)
```

Every point(p1,p2) along the grid

```
new_x=p1*np.cos(-alpha) - (p2)*np.sin(-alpha) + x[4]
new_y=p1*np.sin(-alpha) + p2*np.cos(-alpha) + y[4]
```

Pay attention to direction of bearing.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/28225963)

Comment: I edited the response. Can you remove the "recommend deletion"